# How made Regex "OR" below

Tags: regex

How to create a regex to match these random replies:

```
123456780192
```

or

```
N1234ABC80192
```

Any idea? I tried

```
[0-9]{8,16}|[a-z0-9]{8,16}
```

Comment: Are these two strings everything you want to match, or is there a general pattern here?

Comment: @AlekseyBykov Yeah no telling what he wants to constrain the match to yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you improve your question...

[**`[A-Z0-9]{8,16}`**](https://regex101.com/r/qme0Pa/1)

This expression matches both cases you gave.